# My HTML link says “Image could not be loaded” instead of opening my link

Tags: html, css

I`m building a site in which I need to link to a file, but when I click on the link it tries to open an image instead. (it says the image could be loaded)

```
                 <img src="http://www.bricho.com/demo/brian/with-particles/img/portfolio-img.jpeg"> 
              <div class="img-overlay popup-gallery" href="/portfolio/project.html">  
                <div class="img-overlay-text">

                  <h3>HTML/CSS/JavaScript Project</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Does anyone know the solution to make the link work?

Comment: Change that `div` with the `href` on it to an [anchor tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).

Comment: <div> does not support an href attribute, you need to use onclick="window.location = 'yourlink';" for that. Or you need to turn the <div> in an <a> element

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to link to file is inside (a tag) like this :

`<a href="/portfolio/project.html"> Link </a>`

if you want to use a clickable image just insert it in the (a tag) like this:

`<a href="/portfolio/project.html">
    <img src="http://www.bricho.com/demo/brian/with-particles/img/portfolio-img.jpeg"">
    </a>`